# Touchpad not working on Asus FX753VD

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, asus, acpi, elantech

I've bought a Asus FX753VD and have ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed in dualboot with win10. In order to have ubuntu working I had to disable ACPI in the grub config (pci=noacpi). Once ubuntu is running the touchpad is not working and to my surprise it's not even listed in xinput, it'd be an elantech from what's my current understanding.

I've a friend who has the 553 model of the same series and is running Mint without disabling anything and have the touchpad working fine. So I tried the Mint live and apparently everything works, so I installed it and it can't shutdown and had to do it manually. Once I rebooted and select Mint from the grub menu surprise surprise can't pass the splash screen and had to disable ACPI...

Googling the problem I went across a number of solutions which suggested that a kernel update will do the job, so I updated the kernel from 4.15 to 4.20 and nothing changed for the situation.

My xinput

```
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Comfort Mouse 4500   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Comfort Mouse 4500   id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My lsdev

```
Device            DMA   IRQ  I/O Ports
------------------------------------------------
acpi                      9 
ACPI                             0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000     0000-0000
ahci[0000:00:17.0]         23 
cascade             4     2 
dma                            0000-0000
dma1                           0000-0000
dma2                           0000-0000
dmar0                    16 
dmar1                    17 
EC                               0000-0000     0000-0000
enp3s0                   25 
fpu                            0000-0000
i8042                     1 
i915                     27 
iwlwifi                  29 
keyboard                       0000-0000   0000-0000
mei_me                   28 
PCI                            0000-0000
PCIe PME                 18 
PCIe PME, aerdrv      19 20 21 
pic1                           0000-0000
pic2                           0000-0000
pnp                            0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000     0000-0000   0000-0000   0000-0000     0000-0000       0000-0000
PNP0A08:00                   0000-0000 0000-0000 0000-0000
PNP0C04:00                       0000-0000
PNP0C09:01                     0000-0000   0000-0000
rtc0                      8    0000-0000
rtsx_pci                 24 
snd_hda_intel:card0         30 
timer                     0 
timer0                         0000-0000
timer1                         0000-0000
xhci_hcd                 22 
XT-PIC                   12
```

Anybody know how can I fix this? Would be really nice to have the battery live longer than 1 hour and have the touchpad. Thanks in advance